# Pycaret : Got Missing Value error in target col

Tags: python, missing-data, feature-selection, feature-engineering, pycaret

what if target column contains NaN and when pass it as a target col in Pycaret, it's showing missing value error ; all available Imputation Methods working for rest of cols not for chosen target col.

```
s = setup(df, target = 'Life expectancy', numeric_imputation="mean")
```

> **ValueError:** 10 missing values found in the target column: Life expectancy. To proceed, remove the respective rows from the data.

[image: [Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSZLH.png)]

Target column contains NaN and when pass it as a target col in Pycaret, it's showing missing value error , How to Handle Missing values in Target Column ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.